# How to allow spaces in string when searching for position of substring in C?

Tags: c, string, substring

I'm stuck on part of my homework, I had to find the rightmost occurrence of a substring inside of a string.  I have the first part done (can find substring in single word strings), but now I am having trouble with the second part.  I have to use a modified version of getline in order to allow multi-word strings (aka with spaces).  Here's the unmodified code of getline() and the modified strindex() as well (respectively).  I'd love an explanation as well, I have trouble understanding written code sometimes.

EDIT:  So I updated my code, here it is :)

```
/* string index */

int strindex(char str[], char substr[]){

    int str_idx, sub_idx, k, c = -1;

    for (str_idx = 0; str[str_idx] != '\0'; str_idx++) {

        for (sub_idx = str_idx, k = 0; substr[k] != '\0' && str[sub_idx] == substr[k]; sub_idx++, k++)
            ;

        if (k > 0 && substr[k] == '\0')
            c = str_idx;

    }
    return c;
    return -1; //never reached?
}

/* getline 
*
* Variable Dictionary
* ctchars - character counter, increments once each time getchar() is called
* str_idx - current index of the string, starts at 0, increments with loop
* 
*/


getline(char str[], int lim){

    int ctchars, str_idx = 0;

    ctchars=getchar();

    for (str_idx; str_idx<lim-1 && ctchars !=EOF && ctchars!='\n'; ++str_idx)
        str[str_idx] = ctchars;

    if  (ctchars == '\n') {
        str[str_idx] = ctchars;
        ++str_idx;
    }


    str[str_idx] = '\0';
    return str_idx;

}
```

Comment: I have trouble with that code too :( Format it so that it is readable.

Comment: You really really need to pay attention to indenting your code properly. An experienced programmer will *not* be able to read that code just by looking at it, and it would not pass any code review in the real world. Indenting is an essential part of correctly writing code (even if the compiler doesn't require it).

Comment: If you rename your variables to meaningful names, you should have an easier time understanding whatever you're having trouble with.  For example rename getline()'s s to "str", and strindex()'s s to "str", t to "substr" (assuming it's the substring for which to search), and i, j, and k to str_idx, and substr_idx, and whatever the third var is supposed to be (i'm not reading the code too deeply; just suggestions to simplfy).  Then remove 'c' from strindex and use i (since you never actually use 'c').  And your two returns at the end: the 'return -1' will never execute - you already returned c.

Comment: Are there any resources you guys would recommend on code indentation help?  My professors have NEVER gone over what proper code should look like, I've had other people tell me this too, but I never know how to remedy it.

Comment: There's a simple rule of thumb: Whenever you enter a {, indent a bit more. Whenever you leave with a }, indent a bit less (bringing it back to where you were before). If you do single-line blocks (as in `if (...) foo;`, indent the contents of the `if` or whatever a bit more as well. Any halfway decent editor will do this for you as well - ditch that notepad and get anything - _anything_ else :)

Comment: I don't think you need a tutorial, it is just a logical extension of the current scope.  For example, when you begin a block (like with a for loop) it helps of everything that is inside of that block is nested by one level of indentation.  Start another block inside of that block and use another level of indentation

Comment: +1 for asking a Homework question the right way. Don't take to heart the requests for better formatted code, its good advice and not a shot at you personally.

Comment: One way to learn about indenting is to use a source code editor that does automatic code formatting (virtually all IDEs do this, if you're using Windows then http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/ would be a good choice). Once you start writing code that's formatted properly, it will be easier to read, understand, and modify in the future and you'll wonder how you got along without it!

Comment: Right now I use TextWrangler, I'll see if there are any such preferences, I can't imagine there not being any.  Tim, thanks!  I want to actually learn it, not just find an answer.  I'm trying not to take them to heart, so no worries :D

Comment: I am not going to answer this when I previously gave you a perfect "find a rightmost substring in a string" solution, and you never upvoted my solution (the only correct one I think) or accepted any solution as the answer

Comment: I see you made an attempt to fix your indentation, but it was still inconsistent so I corrected it for you. Note how the "body" of each function/if/for/while is further indented than the surrounding code. Indent your code exactly according to that rule.

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks a lot!  Oh and the -1 does work out, if it doesn't find a substring in the main string, then it just returns -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a couple suggestions for you:

```
for (j=i, k = 0; t[k] != '\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++);
```

Break this up; don't cram everything in the for control structure.

```
j = i;
k = 0;
for (;;) {
    if (t[k] == '\0') break;
    if (s[j] != t[k]) break;
    j++;
    k++;
}
```

Get better names for your variables.

```
haystack_inner_index = i; /* get a better name for `i` too */
needle_index = 0;
for (;;) {
    if (needle[needle_index] == '\0') break;
    if (haystack[haystack_inner_index] != needle[needle_index]) break;
    haystack_inner_index++;
    needle_index++;
}
```